# Maria DB: MySQL Server has gone away, nothing in error log

Tags: mysql, centos, mariadb

I'm trying to slurp a database dump into a new database on my server, and I keep getting the following error

> ERROR 2006 (HY000) at line 215: MySQL server has gone away

I've tried setting `max_allowed_packet=16M` in /etc/my.cnf

And editing the command directly: `mysql -u my_db_user -p --max_allowed_packet=1073741824 my_db < my_db.sql`

I still get this error. It doesn't create an error message in the log file, either. I'm running a mariadb fork of mysql (mysql 15.1, mariadb 5.5.52), CentOs version 7.3.1611.

Not sure what to do at this point!

Comment: `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%timeout%';`  How long did it run?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try setting max_allowed_packet=2G in my.cnf.

Comment: Still get `ERROR 2006 (HY000) at line 215: MySQL server has gone away`. Incidentally, I'm not positive that /etc/my.cnf is the mariadb conf file, so that's a problem...

Comment: Based on your database version, refer to the file listed [here](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/configuring-mariadb-with-mycnf/).

Comment: Remember to restart too!